# Showing all dates if there is no data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a report, but i'm having trouble with my query. **Here is my query** :

```
    SELECT a.Tanggal,a.IdMesin,a.PartID,b.PartName,
    SUM(a.QtyPlanning) AS Plan,SUM(IF (a.HasilProduksi <> 'Good', a.QtyProduksi, 0)) AS NG,
    SUM(IF (a.HasilProduksi = 'Good', a.QtyProduksi, 0)) AS OK
FROM
    trans_lhpdthp a
    INNER JOIN ms_partcategory b on b.PartID=a.PartID
WHERE a.Tanggal BETWEEN '2018-01-09' AND '2018-01-12'
GROUP BY a.PartID,a.IdMesin
ORDER BY b.PartName
```

And it give me result like this :

```
|Tanggal   |IdMesin |PartID|PartName|Plan |NG |OK  |
|-------   |------  |------|--------|-----|---|----|
|2018-01-09|BS 120 A|BLXX  |BOTTOM  |5000 |500|4500|
|2018-01-09|BS 120 B|ACLA  |CLAMP   |5000 |600|4400|
|2018-01-12|BS 260 E|SMXX  |RIGHT   |1200 |0  |1200|
```

And I want the result like this :

```
|Tanggal   |IdMesin |PartID|PartName|Plan |NG |OK  |
|-------   |------  |------|--------|-----|---|----|
|2018-01-09|BS 120 A|BLXX  |BOTTOM  |5000 |500|4500|
|2018-01-09|BS 120 B|ACLA  |CLAMP   |5000 |600|4400|
|2018-01-10|        |      |        |0    |0  |0   |
|2018-01-11|        |      |        |0    |0  |0   |
|2018-01-12|BS 260 E|SMXX  |RIGHT   |1200 |0  |1200|
```

Can you help me, any help can be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You would notice that INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN issue is causing your problem. When there is no data in b INNER JOIN will not show records from a. But LEFT JOIN would bring records from a even if you don't have related records in b.

The following should work.

```
SELECT 
    a.Tanggal,
    a.IdMesin,
    a.PartID,
    b.PartName,
    SUM(a.QtyPlanning) AS Plan,
    SUM(IF (a.HasilProduksi <> 'Good', a.QtyProduksi, 0)) AS NG,
    SUM(IF (a.HasilProduksi = 'Good', a.QtyProduksi, 0)) AS OK
FROM
    trans_lhpdthp a
LEFT JOIN ms_partcategory b 
    ON b.PartID = a.PartID
WHERE a.Tanggal BETWEEN '2018-01-09' AND '2018-01-12'
GROUP BY a.PartID,a.IdMesin
ORDER BY b.PartName
```

Comment: it give  same result

Comment: You need to show your sample data for further investigation

Comment: Does this show all 4 days? `select distinct a.Tanggal from trans_lhpdthp a WHERE a.Tanggal BETWEEN '2018-01-09' AND '2018-01-12'` if it does then a left join is all you need. If not all 4 days then something more is needed.

Comment: @Used_By_Alreadyit it gives me one day. so what i have to do ?

Comment: your fiddle doesn't have the joining table ms_partcategory

Comment: @nazim yes but it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you achieve your goal

1. you  have an INNER JOIN on PartID you could try with a natural join
   if it helps.But Even natural or cross join might return all possible combinations so once you obtain the result you can again filter it using where clause.
2. Another way to do this would be is use nested subqueries instead of joins and within your where clause  include party id with null values too.